# Ubuntu server не отображает php

Tags: ubuntu, apache, php5

Ubuntu server не отображает php-скрипт, он просто его дублирует как текст, что делать? Другой модуль находящийся в той же директории отображается и полноценно работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Могу предположить, что забыли <?php указать

Comment: Нет, <?php?> присутвсует, более того на windows через denwer всё работает.

Comment: вероятно, вы не настроили запуск интерпретатора php вашей программой apache. следуйте инструкциям по установке связки apache+php

Answer (score 2):

Считаю, что php уже установлен

Устанавливаем mod_php

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.5
```

Активируем потдержку php в апаче

```
sudo a2enmod php5.5
```

Проверяем присутсвует ли ссылка /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.conf в нем должны быть следующие строки

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Перезапускаем апач и проверяем работу

```
sudo apache2 restart
```

Должно заработать, если будут ошибки уточняйте