# Как запустить php файл?Apache

Tags: php, apache2

Я установил Apache/2.4.18 и PHP 7.2.4-1. Когда захожу на http://localhost вижу Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. Но когда создаю и пытаюсь открыть php файл открывается FireFox спрашивает сохранить ли открываемый файл. Собственно я хочу освоить написание вебсайтов на php но не могу понять как открывать php файлы.

Comment: Не надо повторять вопрос. А по сути - у вас неправильно настроен Apache, в Инете полно настроек .htaccess

Comment: тут наверное не один десяток вопросов с текстом "у меня файл скачивается, а не выполняется" и ответом вида "включите `mod_php`"

Comment: Ну я собственно работаю над ответом, читаю литературу и т. д. Просто ответы типа "у вас неправильно настроен Apache" или "включите mod_php" без обьяснения как его включить не очень помогают.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ubuntu server не отображает php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767041/ubuntu-server-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-php)

Comment: Хорошая инструкция на русском языке - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-ubuntu-14-04-ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```